# ¿Como exportar a PDF un GridView?

Tags: c#, pdf, gridview, exportar

Como menciona el título del post, tengo problemas al tratar de exportar a PDF, encontré códigos interesantes para ello y el que estoy realizando es así:

```
    protected void btnExportar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        ExportGridToPDF();
    }
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

    }
    private void ExportGridToPDF()
    {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=InformacionCompra.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        GridViewInformacion.RenderControl(hw);
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
        pdfDoc.Open();
        htmlparser.Parse(sr);
        pdfDoc.Close();
        Response.Write(pdfDoc);
        Response.End();
        GridViewInformacion.AllowPaging = true;
        GridViewInformacion.DataBind();
    }
```

Sin embargo no puedo si quiera compilar el código por que en la linea de :

```
    public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
    {

    }
```

Me genera un error de que no se encontró ningún miembro adecuado para invalidar.
Y bueno, llevo rato con ello y ya me desesperó.

Quité esa linea de codigo e intente correrlo así y en el método de ExportGridToPDF me generó un error ya que le hace falta el método que me esta causando conflicto...

¿Como soluciono esto?
La verdad ya ni sé donde mover :/...

Saludos.

Comment: El error que usted indica "no se encontró ningún miembro adecuado para invalidar..." es por el override del método VerifyRenderingInServerForm. Por favor especificar que librerías con versión está utilizando, por ejemplo "iTextSharp". Saludos.

Comment: Que tal Eduardo, Si, estoy utilizando itextsharp version 5.0.5.0

Comment: Puede colocar el código del diseñador y el código completo del codebehind y finalmente nos puede Indicar que tipo de proyecto está manejando, es ASP.Net WebForms?